# Why doesn't this WHERE clause return the right datums?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to query a .mdb database, and this is part of the SQL in VB.Net:

```
sql = sql + "WHERE datdatum BETWEEN #" & "15-10-2018" & "# And #" & "31-10-2018" & "#"
```

The where clause is working the way you assume. At the moment I change the first date from `15-10-2018` to `01-10-2018`, it shows all records from `Jan-10` instead of `Oct-01`.

Comment: Because you aren't using parameters.  Never write sql like that, even in practice.

Comment: When the issues are fixed, this will return records up to and including midnight 31-10, but not later that day. Use <1-11 instead of between

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, don't format the dates that way. Dates used for SQL should *always* use the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. For date-only values with no time component, there are some reasons to prefer the lesser-known unseparated variant of the standard format, but that's still ISO8601. So the date values should look like this:

```
sql = sql + "WHERE datdatum BETWEEN #" & "20181015" & "# And #" & "20181031" & "#"
```

or this:

```
sql = sql + "WHERE datdatum BETWEEN #" & "2018-10-15" & "# And #" & "2018-10-31" & "#"
```

Anything else is just begging for the kind of problem in your question, where the actual date read from the string varies based on the culture of the person/device making the interpretation.

This fix might *seem* to work on it's own, but we still need to do more work because of the 2nd issue:

**DON'T USE STRING CONCATENATION TO PUT DATA INTO AN SQL QUERY!**

You should **always** build the query more like this:

```
sql = sql + " WHERE datdatum BETWEEN ? And ?"
```

Concatenation is okay, as long as no *data*, such as a date value, is used. Then you populate the values like this (assuming you have an `OleDbCommand` object named `cmd`):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-15")
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-31")
```

This completely avoids the formatting issue from the question, because you're working with .Net DateTime values. It can sometimes run faster (though it may not matter for Access). And it protects against SQL injection issues, both malicious and benign. IMO anything else is amateurish and borders on professional malpractice.

Comment: Access doesn't understand unseparated ISO8601 and will return a syntax error. It requires either slashes or dashes. On all other accounts, this is an excellent answer.